# MySQL Select where column equals part of string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to figure out if there's a query for this:

Table col value:

```
harken op het strand
```

Input string:

```
Jantje ging harken op het strand omdat hij daar zin in had.
```

Result (1 row): `id "1", value "harken op het strand";`

Input string:

```
Jantje ging met harken het strand op omdat hij daar zin in had.
```

Result: empty.

I understand it has to be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE value LIKE 'Jantje ging harken op het strand omdat hij daar zin in had.'
```

Where `LIKE` is trying to match each part of the string with the database table column rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a slight modification of Gordon's answer, we can try using `REGEXP` here with proper word boundaries:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM yourTable t
WHERE
    'Jantje ging harken op het strand omdat hij daar zin in had.'
    REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', t.value, '[[:>:]]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `LIKE` in the other order:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE 'Jantje ging harken op het strand omdat hij daar zin in had.' LIKE CONCAT('%', t.value, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using [`Locate()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function. It *may be* more performant than using `Like %..%`. We will simply check for the first occurrence of the field (column) value (substring) in the input string value. If it exists, we have found a match:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name 
WHERE LOCATE(value, 'Jantje ging harken op het strand omdat hij daar zin in had.') > 0
```